# Defining variables inside return in python functions

Tags: python

I'm learning Python and I was writting this snippet:

```
def some_function(a):
  if a <= 5:
   return b = a + 5
  elif a > 5:
   return b = a + 20
```

When i run it, it appears :

```
return b = a + 5
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

However, if i write it in this way, it works:

```
def some_function(a):
  if a <= 5:
    b = a + 5
  elif a > 5:
    b = a + 20
  return b
```

Why does it works this way?

Comment: Why would you need to define a variable there? All local variables will perish after the `return`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to assign and return a thing in the same line. You can return without assigning a variable like this.

```
def some_function(a):
    if a <= 5:
        return a + 5
    elif a > 5:
        return a + 20
```

Also, you can do this and save a line since you only have 2 conditions. If a is not less than or equal to 5, it goes to the next line.

```
def some_function(a):
    if a <= 5:
        return a + 5
    return a + 20
```

This is also equivalent, else you can't specify a condition, it's a catch all for anything that isn't satisfied earlier.

```
def some_function(a):
    if a <= 5:
        return a + 5
    else:
        return a + 20
```

Both of these are probably preferable stylistically to using elif. Elif is usually for if you have 3 or more conditions like:

```
def some_function(a):
    if a <= 5:
        return a + 5
    elif 5 < a < 30:
        return a + 7
    else:
        return a * 100
```